# Dates and Times in separate columns, convert to datetime in R

Tags: r, date

I am importing some data from NOAA and it has dates and times in separate columns. I searched for an elegant way to append a single datetime column in my R dataframe but was unable. I found a stack exchange question about the inverse but not this one. Is there a simple as.Date command I could run? I am simply using read.table for a downloaded text file and it imports just find.

Buoy data is here:
http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/51202.txt

```
>yr mo  dy  hr  mn  degT    m.s m.s.1   m   sec sec.1 degT.1    hPa degC    degC.1  degC.2  nmi hPa.1   ft
>2012   1   16  3   55  MM  MM  MM  1.4 10  7.2 339 MM  MM  23.9    MM  MM  MM  MM
```

Comment: I presume in the output that 2012 is the year and the 1 at the start of the data line is just a sample identifier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ISOdatetime`, which is just a simple wrapper to `as.POSIXct`.  Make sure to specify the `sec` argument as zero.

```
Data$timestamp <- with(Data, ISOdatetime(YY,MM,DD,hh,mm,0))
```

Answer (score 5):

Yep, you want to paste the date time columns together and then coerce that full string to a date time object.

```
dat <- within(dat, datetime <- as.POSIXlt(paste(yr, mo, dy, hr, mn),
                                          format = "%Y %m %d %H %M"))
```

assuming `dat` is the object containing the buoy data. This adds a new columns that is a "POSIXlt" class object or you could use `as.POSIXct()` if you prefer the other format.

Or, having looked at the file so can use their column names:

```
dat <- within(dat, datetime <- as.POSIXlt(paste(YY, MM, DD, hh, mm),
                                          format = "%Y %m %d %H %M"))
```