# How to create a datetime object from separate date fields?

Tags: r, datetime, date

I have a dataset like this:

```
    Year MM DD HH
158 2010  7  1  5
159 2010  7  1  5
160 2010  7  1  6
161 2010  7  1  6

structure(list(Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), MM = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L), DD = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HH = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"MM", "DD", "HH"), row.names = 158:161, class = "data.frame")
```

How can I create a one datetime object from this data set (new column for this data)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dates and Times in separate columns, convert to datetime in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896901/dates-and-times-in-separate-columns-convert-to-datetime-in-r)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few options, here's one (where `x` is your data.frame):

```
x$datetime <- ISOdatetime(x$Year, x$MM, x$DD, x$HH, 0, 0)
```

You can pass in the correct time zone if need be, see `?ISOdatetime`.

Comment: Nice, `ISOdatetime` is much more convenient than my clumsy `paste` construction!

Answer (score 7):

You can now do this in [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf) using `make_date` or `make_datetime`:

From the cran doc:

```
make_datetime(year = 1970L, month = 1L, day = 1L, hour = 0L, min = 0L,
sec = 0, tz = "UTC")

make_date(year = 1970L, month = 1L, day = 1L)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a your data in a dataframe `x`:

```
transform(x,datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(paste(Year,MM,DD,sep="-"), paste(HH,"00",sep=":"))))
    Year MM DD HH            datetime
158 2010  7  1  5 2010-07-01 05:00:00
159 2010  7  1  5 2010-07-01 05:00:00
160 2010  7  1  6 2010-07-01 06:00:00
161 2010  7  1  6 2010-07-01 06:00:00
```

Comment: as.POSIXct is a much better choice if this is to be a new column in a data.frame

Comment: @mdsumner Yes, good point. It seems to convert it anyway, but I'll put it in explicitly