# Convert several data frame separate columns (year, dayOfYear, Hour, Min, Sec) into a date object/timestamp in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe

First of all, let me say I've been looking to post [Dates and Times in separate columns, convert to datetime in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896901/dates-and-times-in-separate-columns-convert-to-datetime-in-r) but it doesn't work for this case.

I have a CSV file with several measurements, where from the 1st to the 5th column, I have data stamps in the form: Year, DayOfYear, Hour, Minute, Second.
Something like this with the var name **dat**:

```
  Year Day Hour Min  Sec. E1.S1 E1.S2 E1.S3 E1.S4 E1.S5 E1.S6 E1.S7 E1.S8 E2.S1 E2.S2 E2.S3 E2.S4 E2.S5
1 2003 241    0   1  5.87 0.296 0.394 0.657 0.427 0.362 0.559 0.460 0.460 0.526 0.362 0.362 0.493 0.460
2 2003 241    0   5 18.52 0.486 0.543 0.572 0.629 0.372 0.457 0.429 0.829 0.486 0.400 0.286 0.543 0.457
3 2003 241    0  10 10.65 0.514 0.629 0.371 0.657 0.457 0.657 0.429 0.429 0.314 0.400 0.286 0.286 0.343
4 2003 241    0  15  2.76 0.575 0.301 0.411 0.630 0.274 0.466 0.466 0.548 0.438 0.329 0.438 0.493 0.301
5 2003 241    0  20  7.06 0.329 0.274 0.657 0.329 0.521 0.247 0.356 0.246 0.411 0.356 0.438 0.520 0.356
6 2003 241    0  25 11.35 0.486 0.314 0.343 0.372 0.314 0.343 0.457 0.343 0.257 0.343 0.229 0.543 0.372
```

What I need is to "join" all those 5 date fields in just one timestamp field so that I can plot the data correctly and work with it in R.

I've looked at the **ISOdatetime** function, but I can't get it to work (and besides it doesn't seem to have a dayOfYear field anyway). I've also looked at the **POSIXlt** and tried something like:

```
test = within(dat, datetime <- as.POSIXlt(paste(Year, Day, Hour, Min, Sec.),
                                          format = "%Y %D %H %M %S"))
```

But all I get is an empty datetime field appended to my data frame.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The problem was in the dayOfYear format field handle as the correct answer in the post bellow pointed out. I needed to use %j instead of %D and that was enough to just get a column of  for datetime. I corrected the seconds to round them since POSIXlt seems to only use integer seconds:

```
teste = within(dat, datetime <- as.POSIXlt(paste(Year, Day, Hour, Min, round(Sec.)),
                                          format = "%Y %j %H %M %S"))
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Try wrapping parens around `(datetime <- ....)` since otherwise it isn't leaving its scope

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Hi, I tried it and the result is the same. A field full of <NA> for the datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution Using `strptime` with format %j : Day of year as decimal number (001–366).

I assume dat, is your data.frame, First I paste the dates columns

```
dat$date <- paste(paste(dat$Year,dat$Day,sep='/'),paste(dat$Hour,dat$Min,dat$Sec,sep=':'))
```

Then I apply `strptime`

```
dat$date <- strptime(dat$date,format ='%Y/%j %H:%M:%S')

dat$date
[1] "2003-08-29 00:01:05" "2003-08-29 00:05:18" "2003-08-29 00:10:10" "2003-08-29 00:15:02" "2003-08-29 00:20:07" "2003-08-29 00:25:11"
```

PS : Here all your dates are for the same day

Comment: It works! And better, that %j you put there... I put that in my example instead of the %D and now it also works. I just added the round(Sec.) since both POSIXlt and strptime don't seem to take into acount the decimal places in the seconds. Thank you!

Comment: @jbssm ! the key is %j. strptime and POSIXlt use the same format.

Comment: Yes, I now understand that. It was just unexpected to get a field full of <NA> for the datetime (instead of a badly parsed data), so I never even thought it was just that small detail that was missing. Thank you again for the help.